# Subclassing and preserving the names of args and kwargs in python in help()

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I know there are a billion questions about `*args`, `**kwargs`, and `super()`.  This is specifically about getting a legible `help()` function.

I have a base class:

```
class Base(object):
  def __init__(self, arga, argb, kwargc=1):
    self.arga = arga
    self.argb = argb
    self.kwargc = kwargc
```

And I derive this class, in such a way that I would like it to have all the existing initialization arguments, but I would also like it to take more.  For example:

```
class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self, *args, kwargd=2, **kwargs):
    super(Derived,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.kwargd = kwargd # the one I add in the subclass
```

And when I define and inspect a base object:

```
>>> b = Base(1,2)
>>> b.arga
1
```

I get this very helpful information:

```
>>> help(b)
Help on Base in module __main__ object:

class Base(builtins.object)
 |  Base(arga, argb, kwargc=1)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, arga, argb, kwargc=1)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

However, when I define my derived class d:

```
>>> d = Derived(2,4,kwargd=8)
>>> d.arga
2
>>> d.argb
4
>>> d.kwargc  # great, this came for free as expected!
1
>>> d.kwargd
8
```

...I find the `help(d)` is less than helpful:

```
>>> help(d)
Help on Derived in module __main__ object:

class Derived(Base)
 |  Derived(*args, kwargd=2, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Derived
 |      Base
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, *args, kwargd=2, **kwargs)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Highlighting the problem here:

```
class Derived(Base)
 |  Derived(*args, kwargd=2, **kwargs)
```

Just saying "*args" is not as informative as if it told me they were called `arga`, and `argb`.  Similarly, I would like to know that `kwargc` is defined, not just that `**kwargs` is there.

So, I'd really prefer to get information such as the names of `arga`, `argb`, and that `kwargc=1` *just as I can see them in the `Base` class*.

Additionally, I'd like to not have to write them out explicitly---DRYing this is why I'm interested in subclassing instead of just writing the class a second time and rewriting the function init parameters out.

Is there a good built-in way to do this?  If not, what is the most elegant way I can pull this information out of the Base object to populate the help intelligently, so that the user knows the names of the arguments going into the subclass when they check `help`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible, because `Derived` has completely another signature and has nothing similar with `Base` except of derived methods and attributes (if they were not redefined).

If you want to have the same arguments - please use the same definition signature. Otherwise you are getting [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).